# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hvplot.pandas'; 'hvplot' is not a package

Tags: python, hvplot

Trying to use hvplot interactive plots. But unable to make it run.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hvplot.pandas'; 'hvplot' is not a package`

using

```
python 3.10.4
conda 4.13.0
panel                     0.13.0          py310h06a4308_0
pyviz_comms               2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
holoviews                 1.14.8             pyhd3eb1b0_0
hvplot                    0.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_1
pandas                    1.4.2           py310h295c915_0
```

import works fine when tried from the terminal

```
(hvplots) xy@win-712M7G3:/mnt/c/Users/xy$ python
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 31 2022, 08:41:55) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hvplot.pandas
>>> hvplot.pandas.__file__
'/home/xy/envs/hvplots/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hvplot/pandas.py'
```

Error on running notebook

```
(hvplots) xy@win-712M7G3:/mnt/c/Users/xy$ panel serve hvplot_interactive.ipynb
2022-07-07 15:41:10,707 Starting Bokeh server version 2.4.2 (running on Tornado 6.1)
2022-07-07 15:41:10,741 User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
2022-07-07 15:41:10,742 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/hvplot_interactive
2022-07-07 15:41:10,742 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 3112
/home/xy/envs/hvplots/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py
2022-07-07 16:05:08,882 Error running application handler <bokeh.application.handlers.notebook.NotebookHandler object at 0x7ff651f7d780>: No module named 'hvplot.pandas'; 'hvplot' is not a package
File 'hvplot_interactive.ipynb', line 38, in <module>:
"source": [ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xy/envs/hvplots/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/code_runner.py", line 231, in run
    exec(self._code, module.__dict__)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/xy/hvplot_interactive.ipynb", line 38, in <module>
    "source": [
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hvplot.pandas'; 'hvplot' is not a package

2022-07-07 16:05:09,121 WebSocket connection opened
2022-07-07 16:05:09,121 ServerConnection created
^C
Interrupted, shutting down
```

Comment: Already seen this post. As given in my post. I am already using a higher version for `panel`. Also tried using `pyviz` channel without success

Answer (score 2):

Try to run

```
!pip install hvplot
```

in a notebook cell. Maybe it's not using the same python environment.

Comment: Yes checked that. The env is the same. also it shows `requirement already satisfied` message, when trying install from cell. sys.path also points to the same version.

Comment: Also does it not work without jupyter? from a python file?

Comment: Maybe uninstall it and install it again from the notebook...what does "!pip list" display you when you run it in the notebook ?